# Second level caching for One To Many Associations

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, ehcache

I am using Hibernate 3.2.5.

I have a one to many relation between `Department` and `Training` tables. The second-level caching is enabled (Using EHCache) and the below entry is made in both the `dept.cfg.xml` and `training.hbm.xml files for caching the data.

```
<cache usage="read-only" />
```

**Problem Description**

For the first time, DB hit is done for getting both the `Dept` and `Training` records. The second time, the `Department` data is fetched from the cache but for getting the `Training` data, a DB hit is done again - WHY? I want this `Training` data also to be fetched from the cache rather than hitting the DB every time.

This is **Dept.java** file:

```
private int deptId;
private String deptName;
private Map trainingDetails;
```

I have mentioned the mapping in the **dept.hbm.xml** file as follows:

```
//Mappings between POJO and DB Table
<map name="trainingDetails" inverse="false" cascade="delete" lazy="false">
      <key column="DEPT_ID"></key>          
      <map-key formula="ID" type="integer"></map-key>
      <one-to-many class="com.model.Training"/>          
</map>
```

This is the code I tried:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("trial.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Dept department = (Dept)session.load(Dept.class, 1);
    //Some business related operations
    session.flush();
    session.close();
            //Some operations
            Session session1 = sf.openSession();        
    Dept department1 = (Dept)session1.load(Dept.class, 1);
    //Here I can see in the console the query for fetching the 
    //training details for the department is getting executed again
    //but the Department details is getting fetched from the Cache - WHY?
    //I want the Training details also to be fetched from the cache.
    session1.flush();
    session1.close();
```

Kindly let me know what am I missing and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you tell Hibernate to cache `Department` entities in the second level cache, for each cached `Department` it will store the values for the `deptId` and `deptName` fields. However, it doesn’t by default store the contents of the `trainingDetails` field. If a `Department` is read from the second level cache and the application needs to access the members field, Hibernate will go to the database to determine the current members of the collection.

If you want Hibernate to cache the contents of the members field, you need to tell it to do so by adding a `cache` element to the `members` declaration:

```
//Mappings between POJO and DB Table
<map name="trainingDetails" inverse="false" cascade="delete" lazy="false">
      <!-- Cache the ids of entities are members of this collection -->
      <cache usage="read-only" />
      <key column="DEPT_ID"></key>          
      <map-key formula="ID" type="integer"></map-key>
      <one-to-many class="com.model.Training"/>          
</map>
```