# Making many to many relationship cacheable in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Role`. There is a third table called `UserRole` mapped as a join-table.

In JPA I can cache `User` and `Role` using `@Cachable`; however when I try to fetch the `Role`s associated to the `User` which is defined `EAGER`, a database query is executed to fetch the values from the join-table.

How can I cache the join-table between `User` and `Role`?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388780/second-level-caching-for-one-to-many-associations But this is specific to Hibernate

Comment: putting @cacheable is all you need to do, then it's down to whether your JPA implementation supports caching relation fields. Some other JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus JPA) support that.

Comment: Looks like hibernate doesn't support it, although there are other annotations available in hibernate with which this can be achieved. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Decide your caching concurrency strategy based on [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html) and use @Cache on top of your association:

```
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "user_roles")
```

Make sure to mark the both entities (in this case User and Role) with @Cacheable too.